# strstr - Not working correctly with XML Response (Symbols)

Tags: php, strstr

Edited post requested by Michael.

```
$Response = $soapClient->__getLastResponse();
$pos = strpos($Response, ">");
echo substr($Response, $pos+1);
// Returns soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> Product already exists

$Response = $soapClient->__getLastResponse();
$converted = (string)$Response
$pos = strpos($converted, ">");
echo substr($converted, $pos+1);
// Returns soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> Product already exists
```

---

I am using an API and wanting to use the response as an error message. The response looks like the following:

`soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> Product already exists`

I am trying to remove everything before `Product` so I just have the error message to display to a user. However when I use this, I get the following in return.

`>soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> Product already exists`

This is the code I am currently using. Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
$Response = $soapClient->__getLastResponse();
echo $Response;
// Shows the below
// soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> Product already exists

$test =  strstr($Response, '>');
echo '<br>'
echo $test;
// Shows the below
// >soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> Product already exists
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Response = "soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. --- >   Product already exists";
$pos = strpos($Response, ">");
echo substr($Response, $pos+1);
```

Comment: Hi @Michael this returns the following `soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> Product already exists`

Comment: That's strange... Take a look at the php sandbox:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a239f502623c69f88d81a2f0c74e665f3d55171

Comment: Can you paste your code with the modifications I suggested?

Comment: sure, edited first post. I'v added two versions (one I tried to force into a string).

Comment: You need to put a ";" at the end of your statements. Your $Response is string, right? Can you post the rest of your code? 
This should work with the info you provided. Did you try the link to the php sandbox?